# Changing T type int in local window

Tags: c#, debugging, generics, runtime, visual-studio-2015

I can't change this "value" variable from locals or immediate window.
Whats wrong? T isn't a **int** in runtime? 
[image: Whats wrong?]

[image: http://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3735159626.gif]

i can't change _value too.I think this is a bug or something?

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Just<int> just = new Just<int>();
            just.Try(5);
        }
    }
    class Just<T>
    {
        private T _value;
        public void Try(T value)
        {
            this._value = value;
        }
    }
```

---

> Beside using this, tried to use instance of Just, worked fine

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me (VS 2013). What version are you using?

Comment: VS Community 2015  ( 14.0.25425.01 Update 3)

Comment: I was able to reproduce this error in VS 2015 professional.

Comment: Please publish code with your images,

Comment: Beside using `this`, tried to use instance of `Just<int>`, worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the expression evaluator.  There is a GitHub issue tracking this bug [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6576)

Answer (score 0):

This error is "normal".
It seems, the debugger doesn't get the value that you enter as `T = int` but simply as `int` (it's written on the debugger that it expects an `int`), and then tries to convert your `int` to `T`. Even if `T` is of type `int`, it can't do the conversion implicitly (usually you just have to cast your value to resolve this kind of errors), it might recompile your value on the fly with the same configuration used to compile your code. And in this configuration `value` is of type `T = unknown`, not `T = int`.

*I guess changing values on the fly doesn't work really like runtime. Because at runtime, `T = int`*
*(Someone that knows better the behavior of the compiler/debugger than me, could maybe, explain you in details what is happening here.)*

---

But like in this method:

```
public void Try(int value)
{
    // With _value as T
    _value = value;
}
```

You would end up with the same error message (and not able to compile it).

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'T'

---

But if you type this in your debugger as value (for your method):

```
(T)(object)10 // Or whatever your int value is
```

Or for the test method above **(that you really should avoid)**:

```
_value = (T)(object)value;
```

It works, the value is changed. (Unless your value is not of type `T`)
You have explicitly converted your `int` into `T`.

---

Nothing wrong, it's just a standard non-generic to generic conversion error.